# How to make a incrementer integer value in a loop

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfPlayers; i++)
{    
   System.out.println("What is your name? ");
   String name = scan.next();
   System.out.println("Choose a color (Red, blue, green, yellow)");
   String color = scan.next();
   int id = players.add(new Player(name, id, color));
}
```

I'm trying to make it so, that the id number is equal to an incrementing number, that increments every time a new player is added. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean you want `int id = i;`?

Comment: `players.add(new Player(name, i + 1, color));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfPlayers; i++) {
    System.out.println("What is your name? ");
    String name = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Choose a color (Red, blue, green, yellow)");
    String color = scan.next();
    int id = i+1;
    players.add(new Player(name, id, color));
}
```

make i+1, instead i issue will be resolved..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the i variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfPlayers; i++) {
    System.out.println("What is your name? ");
    String name = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Choose a color (Red, blue, green, yellow)");
    String color = scan.next();
    int id = i;
    players.add(new Player(name, id, color));
}
```

Comment: So this will be equal to the number of player, So for example player added at index 2 in the arraylist will have id 3?

Comment: If you want to use Id as counter for number of players added, use `int id = i + 1;`.

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop the Player will have id = 0. But you can manipulate the variable i like you want. For example as VPK mention, put the id equal to i + 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int id = 0; // If you persist the IDs in DB, replace with a function to get the latest id
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfPlayers; i++) {
    System.out.println("What is your name? ");
    String name = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Choose a color (Red, blue, green, yellow)");
    String color = scan.next();
    id++;
    players.add(new Player(name, id, color));
// Using variable i like sayd @Patrícia Espada
for (int i = 0; i <= numOfPlayers; i++) {
    System.out.println("What is your name? ");
    String name = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Choose a color (Red, blue, green, yellow)");
    String color = scan.next();
    players.add(new Player(name, (i+1), color));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider changing this line:

```
int id = players.add(new Player(name, id, color));
```

to these:

```
int id = i; // assigning value of "i", that is incremented in each loop, to "id"
players.add(new Player(name, id, color)); // adding new Player to players list using incremented value of "id"
```

You might also write one line instead of two that I have written:

`players.add(new Player(name, i + 1, color))`

as creating `int id` seems to be completely redundant in this loop.